# Finding the number of solutions to this equation in range 50 to 100

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^{2}\; -\; \mbox{floor}\left( x \right)\cdot x\; =\; 83.26$

I was able to find it by graphing and counting the number of intersections within the range, but there has to be an easier way to solve this.

Comment: Hint: $x^2 - \mbox{floor{x}}\cdot x = x(x-\mbox{floor{x}})$

Comment: @Newb:  I would post that as an answer.  Good hint.

Comment: I don't see how that helps - maybe I'm missing something obvious?

EDIT: Could it be that (x - floor[x]) will always be a number between [0,1) and thus, when x is multiplied by that it will become smaller. Thus, x has to be greater than 83.25, as only then can that number multiplied by a fraction give 83.25. Is the answer all numbers greater than 84?

Comment: I think the answer has one solution per interval $[84,85),[85,86),\dots$

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I arrived to the same conclusions as abiessu. There is one solution in the interval [n,n+1] starting at n=84. When n increases, the solution is closer and closer to n. May be, you could consider that x is the sum of an integer and of a number between 0 and 1 and replace in your equation. This is just a suggestion because I confess I do not know how to find the rigourous solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ross Millikan's suggestion, I'm posting this as an answer:

Hint: $x^2 - \mbox{floor{x}}\cdot x = x(x-\mbox{floor{x}})$

Now think about all the possible values that $x-\mbox{floor{x}}$ can take.